# What are the details of different types of Salat?

Tags: salat

I know `Salat` have types like `Farz`, `Sunnat`, `Nafil`, `Wajib`.

I would like to know What is the difference between those? What is the importance of each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Farz and Wajib are the same and means obligatory.

Sunnat and Nafil are the same and means recommended but not obligatory. a slight difference is Sunnat is mostly used for practices done by the Prophet as a role model for us.

> In the Shari'ah (Islamic Constitution) deeds and actions are divided
>   into five classes:
>
> Fardh or Wajib:   فرض او واجـب  An obligatory duty the omission of
>   which is Islamicly punishable.
>
> Mus'tahab:  مسـتـحب  An action which is rewarded, but whose omission
>   is not punishable.
>
> Mu'baah::     مـباحAn action which is permitted but legally is
>   indifferent.
>
> Mak'rooh: مكـروه   An action which is disapproved by the Shari'ah but
>   is not under any penalty.
>
> Haram:  An action which is forbidden, and Islamicly punishable.
>   ([Reference](http://www.islamic-laws.com/hadithoverview.htm))

---

**What is the importance of each one?**

Salat is tool for nearness to Allah and its acceptance is required for acceptance of all other good deeds.

> Salat (prayer) is either obligatory (wajib) or supererogatory
>   (mandub). The most important of prayers are the obligatory prayers
>   performed daily five times, and there is consensus among Muslims that
>   a person who denies or doubts their wujub is not a Muslim, even if he
>   recites the shahadah, for these prayers are among the 'pillars'
>   (arkan) of Islam. They are the established necessity of the faith
>   (al-Din) that doesn't need any ijtihad or study, taqlid.

---

**Reference:**

[Prayer (Salat), According to Five Islamic Schools of Law](http://www.al-islam.org/encyclopedia/chapter7/6.html)